# Angular material mat-divider is not displaying when printing or saving in Firefox

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, divider

I'm encountering an issue with the mat-divider component in my Angular application when trying to print or save a page in Firefox, even using media print css to try make it visible.

**Issue**

When using window.print() function or press Ctrl + P to print or save a webpage, the mat-divider component is not visible in the printed or saved output. However, it displays correctly on the screen in Chrome.

I was able to reproduce using the stackblitz code provided for the angular material official component page: https://v12.material.angular.io/components/divider/overview

**Code:** https://stackblitz.com/angular/byleybgjaxy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdivider-overview-example.ts

My question is, there is a way to make it work and display when printing and saving using Firefox?

**Steps to Reproduce:**

- Open [that link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/byleybgjaxy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdivider-overview-example.ts) in Firefox.
- Type on the console window.print().
- Observe that the mat-divider component is missing in the printed or saved output.

***Obs: You can try on chrome as well, and see this is working fine.***

**Using chrome:**

[image]

**Using Firefox:**

[image]

Comment: It seems working well on Firefox 118.0.1 (64 bit) following your instructions

Comment: I am using the same on windows and as you can see on the print screen I have sent, this is not displaying

Comment: yep....its working fine for me also in firefox